# Sync does not exist when run the update.php script

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I reproduced demo [NewsPlus Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/newsplus_lite) on my site http://druid888.mcdir.ru,but when I update Drupal core and run the `update.php` script I get the error:

> Configuration directory: sync
>   The directory sites/default/files/config_2ds9Pl...-wAgFK.../sync does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an sync folder in an appropriate place on your filesystem, and add this line to your `settings.php` (or `settings.local.php`), e.g.:

```
$config_directories['sync'] = __DIR__ . '/sync';
```

Drupal will create appropriate directories during installation in your `sites/default` or `sites/<sitename>` folder.

Source: [If you have just changed code](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/rebuild) at Drupal.org